# Merging Random Lat/Long Points to Travel Survey Data on Census Tract Field in Pandas

Tags: python, merge, pandas, gis

I have a bit of GIS experience and I'm now trying to learn pandas. Any help would be appreciated. The goal here is to join one point to one person.

I've tried both merge and join but that doesn't give me the right output, way too many values. I've tried massaging the merge output with drop_duplicates and unique methods, but no luck so far.  I've read through the merge documentation and I have this feeling there's a simple method to do this...but so far I haven't found it.

Below are examples of my data and the desired output.

Thanks for any help!

Set 1

```
    XCORD        YCORD       DTRACT
    -74.630496   40.530064   34035053804
    -74.637525   40.557955   34035053804
    -74.628739   40.528239   34035053804
    -74.638959   40.533796   34035053804
    -74.638852   40.510520   34035053804
    -74.638853   40.510527   34035053810
    -74.638858   40.510514   34035053810
```

Set 2

```
     PLSAM           DTRACT
     30000560102     34035053804
     30000560103     34035053804
     30000560104     34035053804
     30000560105     34035053804
     30000560106     34035053804
     30000560107     34035053810
     30000560108     34035053810
```

Desired Output

```
     XCORD       YCORD       DTRACT        PLSAM
    -74.630496   40.530064   34035053804   30000560102
    -74.637525   40.557955   34035053804   30000560103
    -74.628739   40.528239   34035053804   30000560104
    -74.638959   40.533796   34035053804   30000560105
    -74.638852   40.510520   34035053804   30000560106
    -74.638853   40.510527   34035053810   30000560107
    -74.638858   40.510514   34035053810   30000560108
```

As an aside, the background on my task is to generate the appropriate number of random points w/in each census block and join them back to the travel survey data so that it can be visualized in a dot visualizer.

Comment: If the indices of both dataframes match then what happens when you do this `merge(set1, set2, left_idnex=True, right_index=True)`?

Comment: Hi EdChum, I get too many values.  I edited my question to make it more explicit.

Comment: I think in your case as the two dataframes have the same number of rows, all you want is to add `PLSAM` to the other dataframe so the easiest thing to do is just `set1['PLSAM'] = set2['PLSAM']`, this will add the column from set2 to set1, the merge and joins will not work in your case because you have no unique values even though the column values are identical, if this answers your question I will post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is far simpler than you think, the reason the merge and join do not work in your case is that although you have a common column, the values are not unique, this would not be a problem if the indices of both dataframes were the same but in your case it seems they are not.

The simplest and easiest thing is to simply add the column from `set2` to `set1` like so:

```
set1['PLSAM'] = set2['PLSAM']
```

This assumes that the order matches between the two dataframes which appears to be true in your case, or you can of course sort them both first so they are in the same order.

Comment: Hm. Lol.  Yes, that is much simpler...THANK YOU! I used df.sort to get it to line up properly.

Comment: A little wrinkle, the indexes need to match. But after I used data.reset_index(drop=True) it ended up working!  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about `merge`. Maybe it's because I use a lot of databases, but I prefer to the `join` method of the dataframe, and I greatly prefer to have indices defined for each dataframe. Like this:

```
In [97]: df1 = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(5,2), loc=30), columns=['x','y'], index=list('abcde'))

In [98]: df1.index.name = 'DTRACT'

In [99]: df1
Out[99]:
                x          y
DTRACT
a       29.804012  28.999263
b       29.933187  29.602694
c       29.269713  28.577094
d       29.857837  29.634982
e       29.751243  29.020471

In [100]: df2 = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0, high=20, size=(5,2)), columns=['A', 'B'], index=list('bcdef'))

In [101]: df2.index.name = 'DTRACT'

In [102]: df2
Out[102]:
         A   B
DTRACT
b        9  12
c       16   1
d       19  20
e       11  20
f       10  15

In [103]: df1.join(df2, how='outer')
Out[103]:
                x          y   A   B
DTRACT
a       29.804012  28.999263 NaN NaN
b       29.933187  29.602694   9  12
c       29.269713  28.577094  16   1
d       29.857837  29.634982  19  20
e       29.751243  29.020471  11  20
f             NaN        NaN  10  15
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks so much for your response.  I've edited my data above to show what it looks like.  I tried the join method and setting the indexes as you specified, but I still 25 values out instead of 5.  In your example, the dtracts are unique.  In mine there are not. Perhaps this is an important difference.

Comment: @tapzx2 you're right. since the indices aren't unique, `join` won't work. glad you got it all worked out though.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of merge from the pandas docs:

```
merge(left, right, how='left', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None,
  left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=True,
  suffixes=('_x', '_y'), copy=True)
```

Have you tried running this?

```
merge(set1, set2, on="DTRACT")
```

If that doesn't work, the most likely issue is that the indices aren't matching.  My suggestion would be to set the indices of each data frame to be the DTRACT column, and then continue with your merge.

Comment: Hi Kyle, Set 1 and set 2 share the exact same indicies.  I derived set 2 from set 1. I tried the merge method as you specified initially.  I have 141,947 values in set 1 and 2.  I would like to end up with a merge that gives me 141,947 values.  Not 9,480,254 of them.

Comment: The indices might be in the same range, but do they correspond to the same data points?  I know you said set 2 was derived from set 1, but looking at the example data, for each of the indices provided, the DTRACT columns don't match up, which would cause issues similar to what you're experiencing when you try to merge.  Perhaps you could specify how set 2 was derived?

Comment: I put the tracts in set 2 equal to 34035053804.  Then merged them with your suggested method.  I got 25 values out.  I want one point per record.  I hope this clarifies my question.